# Wait for a transaction to be mined ends too soon

Tags: transactions, web3.py, balances

I got a simple python script that sends a signed transaction then wait for the transaction receipt. All is working perfectly, but when I poll my wallet (a metamask wallet) just after the reception of the receipt, the balance is unchanged and it causes me some headaches.
Do you know why the account balance does not immediately reflect the transaction ? Is there something I don't properly understand or forget ?

```
balance = web3.eth.get_balance(my_address)
txn = dict(....)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, my_private_key)
txn_hex = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txn_hex.hex())
balance2 = web3.eth.get_balance(my_address)
assert balance == balance2. # <-- False
```

Is that due to the time the transaction propagates over all nodes ?

Comment: not any idea on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are requesting the balance of your wallet as soon as the transition has been sent, but not mined yet.
Once the transaction is sent it needs to be mined before some of the changes actually happen in your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

> All is working perfectly, but when I poll my wallet (a metamask wallet) just after the reception of the receipt, the balance is unchanged and it causes me some headaches. Do you know why the account balance does not immediately reflect the transaction ? I

Ethereum network consists of 10,000 peer-to-peer nodes. Your MetaMask and your Python script are connected to different nodes. Because of the limits of physics, like light speed, all 10,000 nodes around the world cannot share the same real world state.